# How to cover Promise.all(...) statement with unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I cannot write a test that covers Promise.all() statement within a asynchronous function (loadMessages()) that is ran in setTimeout() block of componentDidMount method.

In componentDidMount there is this.loadMessages() function that is called within setTimeout callback, in order for me to complete my test i need loadMessages() executed.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { conversationId } = this.state
    const POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000

    if (conversationId) {
      setTimeout(() => this.loadMessages(), 0)
      this.timer = setInterval(() => this.loadMessages(), POLLING_INTERVAL)
    } else {
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    }
  }
```

I resolved setTimeout callback with

```
await new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve()
      }, 3000)
    )
```

and that solves a function call, but when start executing a function the report coverage is saying that Promise.all is not covered and function itself looks like:

```
async loadMessages() {
    const { messages, conversationId, errors } = this.state
    let messagesWithAuthors

    // initial load
    if (messages.length === 0) {
      try {
        let initialMessages = await runtime.dais.communication.auto.getMessagesByConversationId(
          conversationId
        )

        const messageAuthors = await Promise.all(
          initialMessages.map(async message =>
            //runtime.dais.orgService.auto.getPersonById(message.sender.id)
            runtime.dais.organization.auto.getPersonById(message.sender.id)
          )
        )

        messagesWithAuthors = initialMessages.map((message, i) => ({
          ...message,
          author: messageAuthors[i],
        }))

        this.setState({
          messages: messagesWithAuthors,
          messageAuthors,
          loading: false,
        })
      } catch (error) {
        this.setState({ errors: [...errors, error], hasErrors: true, modalOpen: true })
      }
    } else {
      let updatedMessages = await runtime.dais.communication.auto.getMessagesByConversationId(
        conversationId
      )
      this.checkIfNeedUpdate(updatedMessages)
    }
  }
```

is there some way to mock a values that are returned from Promise.all() into messageAuthors variable?
I am testing using @testing-library/react and my test looks like this

```
 it('ensure that we have chat window shown if we have conversation as a prop', async () => {
    const queries = render(
      <CommWidget runtime={runtime} conversationId="fe3d52fc-ffb3-482a-aedf-79000645ca70" />
    )
    await new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve()
      }, 3000)
    )

    const commWidget = queries.container.querySelector(
      '.ui-comm-widget .ui.segments.comm-widget #chat-window'
    )

    expect(commWidget).toBeInstanceOf(HTMLDivElement)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't put a timeout in your tests that's an anti-pattern. What happens after the promise resolves? Is the page going to change? If so wait for the change to appear. See [this article](https://www.polvara.me/posts/how-to-test-asynchronous-methods/) for an introduction on testing async methods.